# mongod how to discover visible database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-roles

grant readWrite privilege to user `app_admin` like below:

```
db.createUser({"user":"app_admin", "pwd":"itnihao", "roles": [{"role": "readWrite", "db":"app1"},{"role": "readWrite", "db":"app2"},{"role": "readWrite", "db":"app3"}]})
```

The question is user `app_admin` how to discover the visible database `app1`, `app2`, `app3` without the `listDatabases` privilege?

I find the mongod GUI tool `studio 3T`，`Mongodb Compass` can do this.

Comment: have you tried `show dbs`?

Comment: @Saravana  `show dbs` need `listDatabases` privilege

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tcpdump the `studio 3T`, find the [usersInfo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/usersInfo/#dbcmd.usersInfo) can do this.

```
> db.runCommand({"usersInfo": {"user": "app_admin", "db": "admin"}})
{
    "users" : [
        {
            "_id" : "admin.app_admin",
            "user" : "app_admin",
            "db" : "admin",
            "roles" : [
                {
                    "role" : "readWrite",
                    "db" : "app4"
                },
                {
                    "role" : "readWrite",
                    "db" : "app1"
                },
                {
                    "role" : "readWrite",
                    "db" : "app2"
                },
                {
                    "role" : "readWrite",
                    "db" : "app3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```